# preg_match certain img file type

Tags: php, preg-match, expression

need some help with this bit of pregmatch where I want to look for a specific filetype (jpg, jpeg, png). Any help would be appreciated.

The code:

```
$strmatch='^\s*(?:<p.*>)?\<a.*href="(.*)">\s*(<img.*src=[\'"].*[\'"]\s*?\/?>)[^\<]*<\/a\>\s*(.*)$';

if (preg_match("/$strmatch/sU", $content, $matches)) { 
        $leadMatch=1;
    }
```

Right now it does as it is supposed to and returns images, but I want to be able to set image type (ie make it so it doesn't look for .gif)

Thx in advance.

EDIT: Alternatively could it be possible to insert a specific img alt tag to look for, for example alt="thisImage"?

Comment: Are you trying to pull the _entire_ IMG tag out of the HTML, or just the SRC file? You might want to change the `.*` in the middle of the img to `[^\'"]+` so that you don't match ' or " as part of the .*. Is it OK to match all IMG tags, and then weed through them to exclude .gif, or do you need to match only non-GIF in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$strmatch='/^\s*(?:<p.*>)?\<a.*href="(.*)">\s*(<img[\sa-z0-9="\']+src="([a-z0-9]+\.[jpeg]{3,4})"[\sa-z0-9="\']*>)[^\<]*<\/a\>\s*(.*)$/ui';
```

- NOTE i have put the modifiers on the $strmatch at the end, you should use u-ngreedy and i-nsentive(case)

Comment: `$strmatch='^\s*(?:<p.*>)?\<a.*href="(.*)">\s*(<img.*src=[\'"](^[a-z0-9]\.[jpeg]{3, 4}$)[\'"]\s*?\/?>)[^\<]*<\/a\>\s*(.*)$';`

Comment: I have updated my answer with a new one, which i'm confident works, i have tested it myself.  don't forget to upvote and accept as correct :)

Comment: If you have `\/` in the pattern string, it will conflict with the / delimiters used in the call itself, because `\/` will be immediately collapsed into just /. You could use `\\/` in the pattern ($strmatch variable), or use a different delimiter, such as ~.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use something like this to grab the images:

```
<?php

$string = '<a href="index.html" class="bordered-feature-image"><img src="images/3D Logo.jpg" alt="" /></a> <img src="house.png" /> <img src="http://www.google.com/image.gif" alt="" />';

// GRAB THE IMAGES
preg_match_all('~(?<="|\')[A-Z0-9_ /]+\.(?:jpe?g|png)(?=\'|")~i', $string, $images);
$images = $images[0];
print "\nImages From Match: "; print_r($images);
```

You can also, if you'd prefer, store the images in an array and then insert that array into your string.  Not that this is necessary for only 2-3 image types, but it's an option if you have a lot of stuff you are wanting to check.

```
$accepted_image_types = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');

preg_match_all('~(?<="|\')[A-Z0-9_ /]+\.(?:'.implode('|', $accepted_image_types).')(?=\'|")~i', $string, $images);
$images = $images[0];
print "\nImages Pulled In From Array: "; print_r($images);
```

Here is the explanation for the REGEX

```
~  (?<="|\')  [A-Z0-9_ /]+  \.  (?:jpe?g|png)  (?=\'|")  ~i
        ^           ^       ^        ^            ^
        1           2       3        4            5
```

1. `(?<="|\')` This lookbehind checks to make sure that there is a single or double quote before beginning to match our pattern
2. `[A-Z0-9_ /]+` This is a character class of valid image name characters, followed by a plus to require one or more characters for the file name
3. `\.` Matches a literal dot
4. `(?:jpe?g|png)` Non-capturing parenthesis that looks for either jpgs or pngs.  The question mark after the 'e' makes it optional
5. `(?=\'|")` This lookahead checks to make sure that there is a single or double quote after it has matched our pattern

Hopefully that helps!

[Here is a working demo](http://ideone.com/qs67vU)